# Share a queue object between pool processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pathos

I use the `pathos` `ProcessingPool` class to schedule concurrent execution of the `run_regex()` function across multiple cores. The function takes a regular expression as an argument and evaluates list entries for a match. If a match is found, it puts the matching value into `result_queue`.

As I understand, currently each worker process creates a local copy of `result_queue` in its virtual address space. However, I'd like to use this Queue object as a shared memory mechanism in order to access all matches from the main process.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to pass a Queue object into the Pool initializer, so the queue acts as a shared memory section?
2. Is synchronization required with Queue objects?
3. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Code Snippet

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, Queue
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool

result_queue = Queue()
lock = Lock()
data = {}

def run_regex(self, expr):

for key, value in data.iteritems():
    matchStr = re.search(expr, key, re.I)
    if matchStr:
        lock.acquire()
        result_queue.put(key)
        lock.release()
        break

def check_path(self):

    pool = ProcessingPool()
    pool.map(run_regex, in_regex)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can take a look at the [initializer](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) parameter of the `Pool` object.
2. `Queue` objects are already mp safe so there's no need to protect them.
3. You don't need a `Queue` to return values from the `run_regex` function. You can simply return the `key` from the function and it will be made available by the `map` result.

   ```
   def run_regex(expr):
       group = []

       for key, value in data.iteritems():
           match = re.search(expr, key, re.I)
           if match is not None:
               group.append(key)

       return group

   groups = pool.map(run_regex, in_regex)
   keys = [key for group in groups for key in group]
   ```

   or

   ```
   keys = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(groups))
   ```

   The `map` will return the keys grouped by the `run_regex`. You can easily flatten the list afterwards.